# При помощи указателей копировать строку(массив типа char)

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели

Суть задания в том, что нужно при помощи указателей копировать строку(массив типа char), отбросив не значащие пробелы в начале и конце строки, а повторяющиеся заменить одним. При этом не использовать функции и string. Подкиньте пожалуйста хотя бы идею как это можно сделать, только начал учить плюсы и указатели кажутся очень сложными.

Comment: Ну сделайте это с использованием массивов и индексов, а потом воспользуйтесь тем, что `a[i]` - это то же, что и `*(a+i)`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

идея:

1. выделить память под массив, равный размеру строки с которой придется работать
2. пройтись по всем элементам строки (через `for`)
3. если элемент не пробел в начале строки, дублированный символ или пробел в конце строки - вписать его в новый массив, для которого использовать конечно свой индекс

касательно пробелов в начале и конце строки - лучше перед 1) определить где они в начале строки кончаются и в конце строки начинаются, чтобы сделать в 1)

```
for (int index = index_start; index < index_finishh; index++)
```

и ловить только дубликаты